# Join 2 classes - essentially

Tags: c#, design-patterns, oop, wrapper, adapter

I've got a .NET Web Service Reference to a 3rd party WSDL.

In that reference are 2 classes.  Basically these 2 classes are most likely Interfaces on the 3rd Party API side but in .NET end up as 2 proxy classes.

I have a need to combine both these classes into one class.  Why?  Because it's stupid that these are split, they're the service which allows me to make method calls.  The method calls are all split half and half between these 2 proxy classes.

So I want to create a custom wrapper class called ThirdPartyService and somehow essentially inherit both those proxy class's members.  I know you can inherit 2 classes in C# but I don't see how to do this with an interface either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you haven't given us a lot to work with, but you could do this using composition.

```
class Foo {
    public void Frobber();
}

class Bar {
    public void Blorb();
}
```

Then

```
class FooAndBar {
    Foo _foo;
    Bar _bar;
    public FooAndBar(Foo foo, Bar bar) {
        _foo = foo;
        _bar = bar;
    }

    public void Frobber() { _foo.Frobber(); }
    public void Blorb() { _bar.Blorb(); }
}
```

If `Foo` and `Bar` implement interfaces `IFoo` and `IBar` respectively then you can have `FooAndBar` implement `IFoo` and `IBar` too.

In the language of [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_(book)) we would call this the [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Regarding your edit:

> > I know you can inherit 2 classes in C# but I don't see how to do this with an interface either.

No. You can not inherit from two classes in C#. You have to use composition like I already explained.

Comment: Resharper has an option to generate delegating members to simplify this type of thing.  Very useful.

Comment: That looks about right.  Maybe he was thinking that Foo and Bar implement IFoo and IBar, so FooAndBar would likewise implement both.

Comment: I used ServiceA, B and Z and "DoThis" and "DoThat" but yeah, that's what I was gonna say :)

Comment: Didn't know Resharper did that.  Nice feature.

Comment: Steven read the updated post.  They are 2 proxy methods, not interfaces that I need to combine into one custom class of mine.

Comment: @coffeeaddict: Great. My answer still applies. You have to wrap the two classes into a class of your own and delegate the methods appropriately. As @Sam mentions, Resharper can make this easy for you. Otherwise just do as I have done.

Comment: @coffeeaddict: I don't understand your last comment. Is that a question or a statement? Please help me help you.

Comment: @coffeeaddict: You don't need an interface to wrap two classes into one using composition.

Comment: Ok, so you have a master class that exposes 2 property instances.  I don't see though when the caller calls FooAndBar that the caller is able to do FooAndBar instance = new FooAndBar(); and then instance.SomeMethod where SomeMethod is either in Foo or Bar but the caller doesn't know and doesn't need to know becuase I've combined the method signatures between both Foo and Bar. I don't see how yours lets me do that.  It seems to me I still need to know whether the method is in Foo OR Bar and this is what I'm trying to keep my caller form having to do (ignorant of this)

Comment: @coffeeaddict: First, I did not expose any property instances. Note that both `_foo` and `_bar` are private (they are not marked as `private` but the default access modifier is `private` in C#). Second, the caller does not need to know where the method they are invoking is being delegated to. They can just call `Frobber` or `Blorb` as they need and the class `FooAndBar` will delegate appropriately. Third, if you don't want the user to have to pass in instances of `Foo` and `Bar` it's easy enough to modify the constructor accordingly.

Comment: gotcha.  I was just hoping for a way not to have to build out all those method wrappers...looks like there is no way to sort of inherit the method signatures so you don't have to manually type wrappers / delegates for them.  Thanks.

Comment: @coffeeaddict: No, but as mentioned there are tools (such as Resharper) that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to add *some* value to Jason's post, this sort of stuff would also be known as [adapter](http://www.dotnetcube.com/post/Design-Patterns-e28093-Using-the-Adapter-Pattern-in-C.aspx)

Comment: I guess I was hoping for a very straight forward answer to my problem.  Doesn't look like there is one.